# Eclipse grails run as JUnit test

Tags: eclipse, testing, grails, junit

I'm new to using Eclipse for Grails (using STS) and I'm trying to figure out an easy way to run the unit tests. I've seen that I can do it by right clicking `Run As > Grails Command (test-app)`. This works but is slow and the test output goes to the test report html page and has no apparent clickable stack traces.

I can also do `Run As > JUnit Test`, which appears to be much faster and gives me the traditional JUnit console available in non-Grails tests. When running unit tests, is there a difference in the two? Is the grails command setting up other things or doing anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are performing a full blown test with all bells and whistles on. :)

According to the docs:

```
test-app: Runs all Grails unit and integration tests and generates reports.
```

Setting up the container for the integration tests is what makes it more 'expensive'.

You can limit the test cases that are being run by using 'unit:' as a parameter to indicate that only unit tests need to be run. (When not using JUnit directly from eclipse)

In your case you could do:

```
test-app unit:
```

or for a specific FooBarTests.groovy file:

```
test-app unit: FooBar
```

optionally you can add -echoOut or -echoErr to get more verbose output.

[Check out the docs for more info and different phases of testing.](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html)

Comment: So eclipse is smart enough I believe to just run the unit test for that particular class (if you right click on the class and run it). The actual command being run is test-app -unit marketplace.CustomFieldBuilderTests. I was just curious if that was different than running with Run As > JUnit Test

Comment: The tests file extends the GrailsUnitTestCase (Grails 1.3.x) which in turn extends junit.framework.TestCase. The groovy file is compiled into a Java class which is at that point perfectly runnable by JUnit.